# Using alternative transformations in PostGIS on Amazon RDS

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system, amazon-web-services

I am trying to apply the advice in George MacKerron's blog on [Using the OSTN02 transformation in PostGIS](http://blog.mackerron.com/2012/07/03/ostn02-for-postgis/) however I am using the [Amazon RDS](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/) service where I do not have access to the underlying file system.  Any recommendations on if / how this is possible or an alternative workaround for applying more precise transformations from British National Grid to WGS84?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this is not exactly the solution I was looking for but it does seem to be a solid workaround.  The majority of datasets I work with are supplied in file format, shape or fgdb and I use the ogr2ogr and OSTN02 as described [here](https://digimap.edina.ac.uk/webhelp/digimapgis/projections_and_transformations/transformations_in_gdalogr.htm).  For point data in CSV I create a vrt file and use ogr2ogr following advice [here](https://gisforthought.com/loading-csv-xy-data-into-postgis-with-codepoint-open/).  Occasionally I get data as a postgis dump file in BNG, after lots of trial and error I discovered that ogr2ogr will accept both input and output as postgis and this works really well.  On an EC2 instance in the same region as my RDS I connect to the source database with ogr2ogr, point at a local transformation file on the EC2 instance and then give a destination table on the same DB and it seems to work really well and fairly quickly.  A GB scale polygon DB of building outlines processed in a couple of hours.

The code I used is as follows:

```
ogr2ogr \
  -f PostgreSQL -s_srs "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.999601 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +units=m +no_defs +nadgrids=~/ostn02/OSTN02_NTv2.gsb" -t_srs EPSG:27700 \
  -lco schema=MY_SCHEMA -lco precision=NO -lco create_schema=off -nln TABLE_TO_CREATE -lco overwrite=yes \
  -lco geometry_name=geom PG:'dbname=staging' PG:'dbname=staging' TABLE_TO_CONVERT -lco --config PG_USE_COPY YES \
  -progress
```

Not a perfect solution but a good workaround.

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking at exactly the same scenario and haven't found a pure RDS workaround yet. It might be worth raising a feature request for it, but I imagine it will be woefully low priority (look how long pg_routing took to be made available!)

The only practical workaround I've come up with so far is to reproject the data prior to ingest. I'm currently doing this on the fly in python as I insert (as I need everything in web mercator anyway for this application) but will likely set up a docker container that downloads and installs the OSTN02 and OSTN15 datum shift grids automatically in the next couple of days to make things a bit easier going forwards.

Comment: Hi James, thanks for the post, I came to the conclusion i.e. some kind of external pre process. I will raise a feature request anyway but as you say it will probably be some time coming. I’m at FOSS4G UK in a couple of weeks so will see what I can find out there. Let me know how the Docker approach goes.